# How to decorate the httpclient to send requests with oauth authentication?

Tags: java

I'm creating a HttpClient bean (Java 11 - httpclient) using a new class that decorates HttpClient, so that I can solve
 the following two problems:

1- Add a standard timeout on request (resolved)

2 - Add authorization headers automatically in the request to use Oauth tokens (The problem to be solved)

We can see the status of the code below:

```
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HttpRequest extends java.net.http.HttpRequest {

    protected final java.net.http.HttpRequest delegate;

    private final HttpClientConfig config;

    @Override
    public Optional<BodyPublisher> bodyPublisher() {
        return delegate.bodyPublisher();
    }

    @Override
    public String method() {
        return delegate.method();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Duration> timeout() {
        return delegate.timeout().isEmpty() ?
                Optional.of(config.getDefaultTimeout()) : delegate.timeout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean expectContinue() {
        return delegate.expectContinue();
    }

    @Override
    public URI uri() {
        return delegate.uri();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<HttpClient.Version> version() {
        return delegate.version();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders headers() {
        //TODO How to return an HttpHeaders with new headers if it is built during Request and Response and is immutable?
        return delegate.headers();
    }
}
```

The big problem is how can I return HttpHeaders with the addition of the header authorization, it is an immutable object and is only created during the resquest and resonse build?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to get a library that specifically does OAuth.  Why do you want to use `HTTPClient`?

Comment: Because it is already the standard implementation of java, I would just like to decorate this class and use it, theoretically just add an Authorization header with the token, I don't think an extra lib is necessary for this.

Comment: I researched some more and I think the best way to solve the authentication problem is to create an Authentication and add it to the http client through the builder, the problem is that I have no idea how to set up Authentication using token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a decorator for the class, I created another class responsible for managing the access token, so when I do a getAccessToken() this method already performs the necessary validations and refreshes the token if necessary, so I only have than adding the Authorization header to the requests I want and calling my method to get an updated token.